# Getting posts ID in WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to update custom fields, I have done a query using wordpress and it returns a row, the row seems to be an object and I cannot extract the posts ID from it.

```
$wpdb->query('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = "' . $result['name'] . '" AND 
post_status = "publish"'); 
if ( $wpdb->num_rows ) { 
  update_field('field_570e529aa4a41', $result['runs'], $post_id); 
  update_field('field_570e52a7a4a42', $result['wins'], $post_id); 
  //echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($wpdb);
  //echo '</pre>'; echo 'This Horse is already in the database so we 
  //just updated its statistics'; 
} else {

}
```

Comment: What does `$wpdb` return ? can you please `print_r` that result ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are executing query with `$wpdb->query` but not using its return object.

**SOL 1 :**

Use `$wpdb->get_results()` with second parameter which is return record set type `ARRAY_A`

```
$SQL = "your query here";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $SQL, ARRAY_A );

$post_id = $result['ID']; // with single record set.
```

or multiple records use `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($result as $val) {

 $post_id = $val['ID'];
echo $post_id.'<br>';
}
```

**SOL 2 with your code :**

```
$rows = $wpdb->query( 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "' . $result['name'] . '" AND post_status = "publish"' );
        if ($rows) {
            foreach ( $rows as $key => $rc ) {
                update_field( 'field_570e529aa4a41', $result['runs'], $rc->ID );
                update_field( 'field_570e52a7a4a42', $result['wins'], $rc->ID );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not querying for a single result, a list instead so you should loop through it, something like this:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = "' . $result['name'] . '" AND post_status = "publish"'); 
    if ( $results ) { 
      foreach( $results as $key => $row) {
         update_field('field_570e529aa4a41', $result['runs'], $row->ID); 
         update_field('field_570e52a7a4a42', $result['wins'], $row->ID);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thats it! I need to look and research into $key = $row as thats what solved the issue! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = "' . $result['name'] . '" AND post_status = "publish"'
);

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
    echo $fivesdraft->ID;
}
```